# any standard JDK interface similar to Callable<V> but that throws no checked exception?

Tags: interface, java

I was just wondering if there is a standard interface with a signature similar to this one:

```
public interface I<V>
{
   V getV();
}
```

or this one:

```
public interface I<V>
{
   void setV(V v);
}
```

Comment: Why do you want a generic version of such a thing? `Setters` and `Getters` are used so much that such interfaces wouldn't be useful. I think that you will want to create your own custom interface for your scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to make your own, extending the standard interface `Callable<V>`. This allows you to use it wherever Callable can be used.

```
public interface NoThrowCallable<T> extends java.util.concurrent.Callable<T> {
    T call();
}
```